# jmeter display response time in seconds instead of milliseconds

Tags: jmeter

Is there a setting in jmeter to display all values in seconds instead of milliseconds. 
I usually use excel to do the conversion manually, but was hoping there was some way of doing this automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a temporary solution. Iused the bundled xsl file in the extra directory and edited the display-time section to this

```
<xsl:template name="display-time">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(($value div 1000),'0 s')" />
</xsl:template>
```

and then ran the following command
xsltproc jmeter-results-detail.xsl results.jtl > results.html

The resulting file displays the response times in seconds.